# Lock a folder on Windows system using Java Program

Tags: java, windows

I am trying to lock or encrypt a folder on Windows system using Java code, I was not able to find any other way except linking this batch script in Java code.

```
    @ECHO OFF 

    title lock 
    if EXIST "Control Panel.{21EC2020-3AEA-1069-A2DD-08002B30309D}" goto UNLOCK 
    if NOT EXIST MyFolder goto MDMyFolder 
    :CONFIRM 
    echo Are you sure to lock this folder? (Y/N) 
    set/p "cho=>" 
    if %cho%==Y goto LOCK 
    if %cho%==y goto LOCK 
    if %cho%==n goto END 
    if %cho%==N goto END 
    echo Invalid choice. 
    goto CONFIRM 
    :LOCK 
    ren MyFolder "Control Panel.{21EC2020-3AEA-1069-A2DD-08002B30309D}" 
    attrib +h +s "Control Panel.{21EC2020-3AEA-1069-A2DD-08002B30309D}" 
    echo Folder locked 
    goto End 
    :UNLOCK 
    echo Enter password to Unlock Your Secure Folder 
    set/p "pass=>" 
    if NOT %pass%== password goto FAIL 
    attrib -h -s "Control Panel.{21EC2020-3AEA-1069-A2DD-08002B30309D}" 
    ren "Control Panel.{21EC2020-3AEA-1069-A2DD-08002B30309D}" MyFolder 
    echo Folder Unlocked successfully 
    goto End 
    :FAIL 
    echo Invalid password 
    goto end 
    :MDMyFolder
    md MyFolder
    echo MyFolder created successfully 
    goto End 
    :End
```

Suggest any other method for the problem.

Comment: I think @RahulTripathi's answer is a good suggestion. You should try that.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to zip the folder and then you can assign a password to it. So in this was you can lock your folder.

You can refer this article on how you can [ZIP and UNZIP with Passwords in Java](http://java.sys-con.com/node/1258827)